# Most efficient way to find matching words from paragraph

Tags: php, regex, algorithm, compare, pattern-matching

I have a Paragraph that I have to parse for different keywords. For example, Paragraph:

"I want to make a change in the **world**. Want to make it a better place to live. Peace, Love and Harmony. It is all life is all about. We can make our **world** a good **place** to live"

And my keywords are

"world", "earth", "place"

I should report whenever I have a match and how many times.

Output should be:

"world" 2 times and "place" 1 time

Currently, I am just converting Paragraph strings to array of characters and then matching each keyword with all of the array contents.
Which is wasting my resources.
Please guide me for an efficient way.( I am using PHP)

Comment: 2 min search : http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: @Gerton: Appreciate it, but I am kind of talking about efficient way like Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm or something.

Comment: @Gerton: with this way it is impossible to know if the keyword isn't only a part of an other word.

Comment: @Rishi: php functions are written in C and already implements efficient algorithms for string search. Even the regex engine uses a fast search algorithm to quickly find interesting positions when the pattern contains a literal string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: This is exactly what I was asking for. Now it is very clear in my mind. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Rishi in your string `place` occurs 2x but output you say, want only 1x typo?

Comment: @Jonny5 I want to find out repeatation of specific keywords from paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CasimiretHippolyte commented, regex is the better means as [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) can be used. Further caseless matching is possible using the `i` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Use with [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) return value:

> Returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred.

The pattern for matching one word is: `/\bword\b/i`. Generate an array where the keys are the word values from search `$words` and values are the mapped word-count, that preg_match_all returns:

```
$words = array("earth", "world", "place", "foo");

$str = "at Earth Hour the world-lights go out and make every place on the world dark";

$res = array_combine($words, array_map( function($w) USE (&$str) { return
       preg_match_all('/\b'.preg_quote($w,'/').'\b/i', $str); }, $words));
```

`print_r($res);` [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/384376) *outputs to:*

> Array
>   (
>       [earth] => 1
>       [world] => 2
>       [place] => 1
>       [foo] => 0
>   )

Used [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) for escaping the words which is not necessary, if you know, they don't contain any specials. For the use of inline anonymous functions with `array_combine` *PHP 5.3 is required*.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    Function woohoo($terms, $para) {
     $result =""; 
     foreach ($terms as $keyword) {
        $cnt = substr_count($para, $keyword);
        if ($cnt) {
          $result .= $keyword. " found ".$cnt." times<br>";
        }
      }
      return $result;
    }
    $terms = array('world', 'earth', 'place');
    $para = "I want to make a change in the world. Want to make it a better place to live.";
    $r = woohoo($terms, $para);
    echo($r);
?>
```

Comment: With this way, you may count a lot of false positive. imagine a string that contains the word `worldwide`,  `earthquake` or `misplaced`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Can you recommend me any alternative to find exact word matches ?

Comment: @Rishi: `$count = preg_match_all('~\bworld\b~', $para);`. It's about 10x slower than using `substr_count` but it's even very fast and only whole words are taken in account.

Answer (score 0):

I will use `preg_match_all()`. Here is how it would look in your code. The actual function returns the count of items found, but the $matches array will hold the results:

```
<?php
$string = "world";

$paragraph = "I want to make a change in the world. Want to make it a better place to live. Peace, Love and Harmony. It is all life is all about. We can make our world a good place to live";

if (preg_match_all($string, $paragraph, &$matches)) {
  echo 'world'.count($matches[0]) . "times";
}else {
  echo "match NOT found";
}
?>
```

Comment: Your pattern doesn't have delimiters (test your code and see the warnings). The main interest to use `preg_match_all` instead of `substr_count` is that you can use word boundaries to be sure you have an entire word (and not a substring that is only a part of another word). Note: for this particular task the third parameter of `preg_match_all` isn't required since the function returns the number of occurences. The if condition isn't very useful too.