# Get the string before replace

Tags: php

How can I get the word that I'm about to replace?...

```
<?php
$string = "Delivery (fail) with error 500";
$words = ['fail', 'error', 'abuse'];
$exist = ($string != str_ireplace($words,"XX",$string)) ? true: false;
if($exist) {
// Do some magic...
}
```

This has been the most "elegant" way that I could find if string has a particular word, but how do I know which of the 3 or 4 or xN words is the one that is begin replace...
If the string has 2 or 3 of the array words I only care for one it doesn't matter if the first or last as long as I know which of the word in the array where fund...
Does any one know how to do it with out a `foreach` or `for` or `while` or any `loop` for that matter...
Thank you in advance...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to find matching words from paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933670/most-efficient-way-to-find-matching-words-from-paragraph)

Comment: @RobinSingh, thank you, I have try that answer, the thing is, that it returns an array, I have try getting the first key for the word that is begin replaced but is not consistent, say that the first time it was "Fail", but the second time is "Abuse", and that is the inconsistent, it has to be always the same it doesn't matter which...